# Performance issue using Symfony2 form component

Tags: performance, forms, symfony

I have a performance issue using Symfony2 Form Component,
I'm using this component to create a form which contains 300 checkbox(s). This form must be flexible (The checkbox(s) should be created on a SET_DATA event using a given data tree.
I'm also using Subscribers to make my form flexible.

**The problem:**

- The form generation took an average of 900 ms (which is a substantial amount of time given the input size)
- Binding my form took much more time (an average of 1sec)

**Assumptions:**

- The propertyPathMapper is taking too much time to create paths and look for the right one to get error messages on validation.

**My Question:**

- In the case of the PropertyPath issue, do you know how to fix it? If it's not, any ideas on how to optimize my form?

**Our Code:**

I created a github Gist > https://gist.github.com/2867617

- data.array is the data format we are using to generate our search form. (the tree can have many sub levels & is created from our database)
- SearchType.php is our main Search Type
- The other classes we are using are helping us to iterate on and generate all the search criteria elements.

PS: We are using the 2.0.15 version of Symfony2 ,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

- You can solve first problem by caching the generated form html with Memcache. Remember to invalidate the cache index after saving the form.
- With the second problem Use a profiler to check what is taking so long, it may be Doctrine hydration issue.